# Searching for keywords irrespective of special characters in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with a column of some texts:

```
texts
This is really important(actually) because it has really some value
This is not at all necessary for it @ to get that
```

I want to perform a search and obtain the texts with keywords like "important(actually)", and it doesn't seem to work.

How do I to get that information?
I have used the following code:

```
df_filter=df[df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(keyword, flags=re.I)).any(axis=1)]
```

But I am unable to get  such information.

Comment: @Jan can I give a list of flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape the special characters in regex

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'texts': [
                             'This is really important(actually) because it has really some value',
                             'This is not at all necessary for it @ to get that']})

keyword = 'important(actually)'
df[df.apply(lambda x: 
            x.astype(str).str.contains(
                re.escape(keyword), flags=re.I)).any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
    texts
0   This is really important(actually) because it ...
```

Comment: unfortunately there are many such words and this just works for one word only

Comment: You can use re.escape to escape special characters. You dont have to manually escape them.

Comment: I tried your code.It doesn't work.When I search in my text with re.escape,it results in an empty dataframe

Comment: @SriTest Can you please update the question with the case you are not able to reproduce. The reason being the example you posted in the question can be solved by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`contains` use regex and brackets are special chapter in regex
You can disable the regex by add `regex=False`:

```
    df_filter=df[df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(keyword, regex=False)).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: It doesn't work.When I use this, I don't get any result.Also, I need to ignore the case. So this doesn't work for me

Comment: you can set the keyword as `keyword = 'important\(actually\)'` and it will work

Comment: and you can `use re.escape` to do it